# When/why doesn't pkg-config return library link-path?

Tags: linux, libraries, pkg-config

I want to make use of `pkg-config` in my *Makefile* to find the link-path for *libspa-0.2*.

I observe that `pkg-config --libs libspa-0.2` returns nothing.

For simplicity, I'll demonstrate the problem by running `pkg-config` straight from the shell, i.e. not from within my *Makefile*.

```
$ uname -a
Linux MY_LINUX_PC 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
$ sudo apt-get install -y libspa-0.2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  pipewire-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libspa-0.2-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/81.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 625 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libspa-0.2-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 34966 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libspa-0.2-dev_0.3.48-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libspa-0.2-dev:amd64 (0.3.48-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libspa-0.2-dev:amd64 (0.3.48-1ubuntu3) ...
$
$ pkg-config --libs libspa-0.2

$
```

Oddly, `pkg-config` behaves as expected when asked to report *libspa-0.2*'s cflags:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags libspa-0.2
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/spa-0.2
$
```

This is the content of *libspa-0.2.pc*:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libspa-0.2.pc
prefix=/usr
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

plugindir=${libdir}/spa-0.2

Name: libspa
Description: Simple Plugin API
Version: 0.2
Cflags: -I${includedir}/spa-0.2 -D_REENTRANT
$
```

...so I was expecting `pkg-config --libs libspa-0.2` to return something along the lines of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

**Why does `pkg-config --libs libspa-0.2` return an empty string?**

I'd be grateful if a knowledgeable answerer can describe a little about the relationship between `pkg-config`, `apt-get`, and the content of the respective `.pc` files.

I would like to understand the problem/observed behavior specifically with respect to *libspa-0.2-dev*, but if there is a generalization, I'd like to learn that as well.

---

**Update**: this is weird -- it looks like `pkg-config` is doing some (intelligent) formatting/stripping of content for the library link-paths. This is the content of *zlib.pc* -- something preinstalled (which should rule out my messing up):

```
$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sharedlibdir=${libdir}
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: zlib
Description: zlib compression library
Version: 1.2.11

Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -L${sharedlibdir} -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
$
```

...and this this what `pkg-config` reports for its library link paths:

```
$ pkg-config --libs zlib
-lz
$
```

...i.e. it seems to be stripping out the `-L${libdir} -L${sharedlibdir}` part.

At least the behavior is consistent...which maybe implies this isn't a "problem" but defined behavior of `pkg-config`. But I can't figure out the rationale of why it's behaving this way: when and why does it strip out the library link-paths, i.e. `-L` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `pkg-config --libs libspa-0.2` return an empty string?

`libspa-0.2` is a headers-only package, it doesn’t ship any libraries. That’s why its `.pc` file doesn’t specify a `Libs` entry.

> When and why does it strip out the library link-paths, i.e. `-L` content?

`pkg-config` strips arguments which are already known to the compiler. On your system, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is the default library path and the compiler knows about it, so it doesn’t need to be specified with a `-L` option. This behaviour can be disabled with the `--keep-system-libs` option (at least, with the `pkgconf` implementation of `pkgconfig`, which is probably what your system uses):

```
$ pkg-config --keep-system-libs --libs zlib
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz
```

But it only includes `-L` if an `-l` option is actually required, so it doesn’t show up for `libspa-0.2`:

```
$ pkg-config --keep-system-libs --libs libspa-0.2
```

(There’s an equivalent flag for `CFLAGS`, `--keep-system-cflags`.)